# side effects of using transactions of PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have recently switched to PDO, and I have read about transactions, but after some readings, I am still confused about some aspects of using transactions.

1. I have read that Long-Running Transactions causes a lock, so how to prevent this?
2. are there any other problems (apart from Long-Running Transactions)  which might occur when using transactions and how we can tackle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to point 1. is simple: Don't run transactions for very long.

Your question 2 is very broad.